# DeleteUrlCacheEntryA Not clearing the cache

Tags: c++, winapi

I've been trying to use the function `DeleteUrlCacheEntryA` and it doesn't seem to be clearing the cache.

Heres how im using this function:

```
void Clear(std::string s)
{
 DeleteUrlCacheEntryA(s.c_str());
}

Clear("127.0.0.1/api.php?ac=login&user=test&pass=test12");
```

I do a message box with a download string function(which clears the cache of the provided url everytime my download string function is called.) and it gives me nothing much for my return.

Heres what i get in my c++ application

```
{"username": "null", "password":"null"}
```

My webserver php echoed:

```
{"username": "test", "password":"test12"}
```

Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the docs? "Returns TRUE if successful, or FALSE otherwise. To get extended error information, call GetLastError."

Comment: I already tried that. Thanks

Comment: ... yeah, so maybe you should share that kind of information... and post the result. We cannot look on your computer.

Comment: Please post `DeleteUrlCacheEntryA`'s error messages. It looks like the APIs updated the website to https, so while the url redirected, the cache entry did not match.You should change the http address to https.

Comment: [Try enumerating the cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/caching#enumerating-the-cache) before using the function `DeleteUrlCacheEntryA`.

Comment: Did you try prefixing `127.0.0.1` with `http://`? `DeleteUrlCacheEntry()` expects a complete URL.

Comment: Yes i have tried that. I did the GetLastError() function and its returning me 2 for some reason

Answer (score 0):

[Try enumerating the cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/caching#enumerating-the-cache) to see possible parameters for DeleteUrlCacheEntryA.

```
int WINAPI EnumerateCacheOld()
{
    DWORD dwEntrySize;
    LPINTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO lpCacheEntry;
    DWORD MAX_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO_SIZE = 4096;
    HANDLE hCacheDir;
    int nCount = 0;

    //SendDlgItemMessage(hX, IDC_CacheList, LB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);

    //SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_WAIT));

    dwEntrySize = MAX_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO_SIZE;
    lpCacheEntry = (LPINTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO) new char[dwEntrySize] {};
    lpCacheEntry->dwStructSize = dwEntrySize;

again:

    hCacheDir = FindFirstUrlCacheEntry(NULL,
        lpCacheEntry,
        &dwEntrySize);
    if (!hCacheDir)
    {
        delete[]lpCacheEntry;
        switch (GetLastError())
        {
        case ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS:
            TCHAR tempout[80];
            StringCchPrintf(tempout,
                80,
                TEXT("The number of cache entries = %d \n"),
                nCount);
            //MessageBox(hX, tempout, TEXT("Cache Enumeration"), MB_OK);
            FindCloseUrlCache(hCacheDir);
            SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW));
            return TRUE;
            break;
        case ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER:
            lpCacheEntry = (LPINTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO)
                new char[dwEntrySize];
            lpCacheEntry->dwStructSize = dwEntrySize;
            goto again;
            break;
        default:
            ErrorExit(
                TEXT("FindNextUrlCacheEntry Init"));
            FindCloseUrlCache(hCacheDir);
            SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW));
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    //Here lpszSourceUrlName
    //SendDlgItemMessage(hX, IDC_CacheList, LB_ADDSTRING,0, (LPARAM)(lpCacheEntry->lpszSourceUrlName));
    nCount++;
    delete (lpCacheEntry);

    do
    {
        dwEntrySize = MAX_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO_SIZE;
        lpCacheEntry = (LPINTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO) new char[dwEntrySize] {};
        lpCacheEntry->dwStructSize = dwEntrySize;

    retry:
        if (!FindNextUrlCacheEntry(hCacheDir,
            lpCacheEntry,
            &dwEntrySize))
        {
            delete[]lpCacheEntry;
            switch (GetLastError())
            {
            case ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS:
                TCHAR tempout[80];
                StringCchPrintf(tempout,
                    80,
                    TEXT("The number of cache entries = %d \n"), nCount);
                //MessageBox(hX,tempout,TEXT("Cache Enumeration"), MB_OK);
                FindCloseUrlCache(hCacheDir);
                return TRUE;
                break;
            case ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER:
                lpCacheEntry =
                    (LPINTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO)
                    new char[dwEntrySize];
                lpCacheEntry->dwStructSize = dwEntrySize;
                goto retry;
                break;
            default:
                ErrorExit(
                    TEXT("FindNextUrlCacheEntry Init"));
                FindCloseUrlCache(hCacheDir);
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        //Here lpszSourceUrlName
        //SendDlgItemMessage(hX,IDC_CacheList, LB_ADDSTRING,0,(LPARAM)(lpCacheEntry->lpszSourceUrlName));
        nCount++;
        delete[] lpCacheEntry;
    } while (TRUE);

    //SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW));
    return TRUE;
}
```